# How to use VS Code Contribution Points to configure a file path?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I want to add a configuration possibility to my VS Code extension that allows the user to set a path to a specific file. From my understanding, Contribution Points could be used to serve that purpose.
I tried to follow the documentation but my implementation does not seem to work as intended.

I added the following to the respective .json files

package.json:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "title": "File Path",
      "properties": {
        "config.path": {
          "type": ["string", "null"],
          "default": null,
          "description": "Path to some file"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

settings.json:

```json
"config.path": "/path/to/file.txt"
```

Inside my extension.ts:

```js
const config:vscode.WorkspaceConfiguration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("myExtensionName");
const path:string|null|undefined = config.get("config.path");
```

I would expect the file path to be contained in the variable "path", which is apperently not the case.

Does the "properties" entry in package.json only accept predefined stuff or is "config.path" fine here?
Do Contribution Points work at all or is there another way to allow the user to configure an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `getConfiguration` command does not load the configuration previously defined. You don't have to use the *extensionName*, but instead, the `section`, which is `config` on your sample. BTW, it's a confusion that is fairly common to have on first use.

So, the code should be:

```js
const config:vscode.WorkspaceConfiguration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("config");
const path:string|null|undefined = config.get("path");
```

But, as a convention on extension development, you *should* declare the configuration as `yourExtensionId.path` instead. Because the user would know the extension `yourExtensionId` has a setting called `path`.

Hope this helps

#### New suggestion after your first comment

I would suggest you a different setting config.

```json
      "properties": {
        "config.path": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "",
          "description": "Path to some file"
        }
      }
```

While loading, use:

```js
const path = vscode.WorkspaceConfiguration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("config").get("path", "");
```

The second parameter in the `get` function defines a default value. If nothing is set in `settings.json`, it will return "" (in your case).

Comment: OK, the "first part" works now, as I can read the default value from the configuration. But the value set in settings.json does not show in my "path" variable. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "first path", since you set the "default" value as null. But, I would suggest you a different setting config. Answer updated...

Comment: So with "I would suggest you a different setting config." you mean that I should put that inside settings.json? But even if I do so it does not work. Even if I set a value inside settings.json the default value of get() is alway returned.

Comment: No, I mean simply use "string" as its type, instead of ["string", "null"]. By the way, be sure there is no setting defined in the workspace/folder you have opened, because from time to time when playing with new settings you may forgot to clean up that and keep reading old values.